# CPU is only used 50% on full load on a Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012-r2, cpu-usage

I use Windows Server 2012 R2 on my home server (it's a mini-ITX PC based on an [Asrock E350M1/USB3 motherboard](http://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/E350M1USB3/index.hu.asp), so it's not a strong enterprise server).

My problem is that even when I run multiple CPU-heavy applications, it only uses 50% of both CPU cores (see screenshot below), but it becomes slow as if it would use all of its CPU power.

What can I do to use the full power of the CPU?

[image: Task manager screenshot]

Comment: 50% of 2 CPU = 100% of 1 CPU, no ? I would guess then your app is not compiled as multicore

Comment: But in the task manager (as it's on the attached screenshot) I see that both cores are used only partly (~0,8 GHz instead of 1,6 GHz). Also, if I open another application (such as a browser) it doesn't use the other core, the CPU load doesn't go over 50%.

Comment: Check the power plan, it might be set to Power Saver or something custom with similar settings that limit CPU speed. Try setting it to High Performance and see what effect it has.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help, both "Minimum processor state" and "Maximum processor state" is set to 100%. (see screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/gWjt5YL.png)

Comment: I found that in my High Performance Power plan it was set to only use 50% of cpu..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem finally by disabling AMD Cool'n'Quiet in the BIOS, after that CPU goes to 100% on full load and CPU speed is 1.60 GHz constantly.